# How to drop composite UNIQUE KEY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question has been asked before, but they all referenced to single and not composite keys, and the solutions don't seem to work for me. Basically, please consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_answers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`question_id`, `user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How do I remove the unique key made of question_id and user_id in this case? I have tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_answers DROP INDEX `UNIQUE`;
```

and
    DROP INDEX `UNIQUE` ON my_answers;

Both of which didn't work, throwing the following error "#1091 - Can't DROP 'UNIQUE'; check that column/key exists"

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please name each key:

    `UNIQUE KEY some_name (question_id, user_id)`

that will make your table much easier to work with in the future.. like when you need to drop a key...

Comment: I would if I was the one who made the table :) CMS environment, etc etc

Comment: as I later said:



Try the following command:
`show index from my_answers;`
then inspect the key name of your index and drop it by its name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not specify a name of the unique key in case of composite key then by default the first column name is used as the name.

Here is the example

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_answers` (
    ->     `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ->     `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
    ->     `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY (`question_id`, `user_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

If you now run `show create table` you can see something as

```
mysql> show create table my_answers ;
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my_answers | CREATE TABLE `my_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `question_id` (`question_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Here you can see that the key name is the first column in the composite key which is `question_id` and you can drop it as

```
mysql>  alter table `my_answers` drop INDEX question_id ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
```

Comment: But what if question_id is defined as FK. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
show index from `my_answers`;
```

then inspect the key name of your index and drop it by its name.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, turns out it was ridiculously simple. Simply remove one of the field as index key:

```
ALTER TABLE my_answers DROP INDEX user_id
```

Turns out this will dismantle the composite key.